# Docker Vue JS Nginx

Tags: vue.js, nginx, docker

В одном `docker-compose.yml` собираются `N` сервисов.
Каждый взаимодействует с `nginx`, который также располагается в контейнерной сети.

## Задача:

- Собрать `frontend` и пробросить собранные файлы в `nginx`.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
...
frontend:
  build: ./FridayWEB
  volumes:
    - frontend_src:/opt/app/
 
nginx:
  image: nginx:latest
  depends_on:
    - frontend
  ports:
    - "8004:80"
  volumes:
    - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    - frontend_src:/usr/share/nginx/html

volumes:
  frontend_src:
    driver: local
...
```

**FrontWEB/dockerfile**

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
RUN mv dist/* .
RUN rm -rf dist/
```

В основном проблема заключается в том, что я не понимаю как пробросить собранные в `frontend` файлы в `nginx`.

Comment: а зачем вам отдельный сервис для фронта, если там нет сервиса вообще, он используется только для сборки? вы можете объединить это используя multi-stage build, собрав ваш фронт, а потом скопировав его в образ к nginx

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Получается, `multi-stage build` закидывать в `dockerfile` `nginx`?  Или как?

Comment: Офф документация: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/. Рабочий пример по сборке фронта: https://github.com/HTMLProgrammer2001/messangerClient/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: да, т.к. фронт это просто набор статических файлов, после сборки вы можете их скопировать к вашему серверу, который и будет их отдавать, тогда у вас получится, маленький самодостаточный образ, который можно деплоить куда угодно

Comment: @ExplodingKitten , спасибо за ответ, но мне просто кажется что засовывать сборку фронта в dockerfile nginx это некое нарушение порядка в проекте. В том плане, что каждый сервис отдельный и вся сборка и конфиги забиваются отдельно в каждой папке сервиса. А тут фронт в nginx.